# using heap helps boost performance for string rearrange

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-2.7, heap

I'm working on the problem below and have posted my code. My question is, my current implementation is using a sort in Python - `sorted(sorted_freq, reverse=True)`. I referred some other implementation which is using a max heap (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-a-string-so-that-all-same-characters-become-at-least-d-distance-away/). I think they have the same time complexity which is `O(n*log n)` (if I calculate wrong, please feel free to correct). So I'm wondering if there is any benefit in terms of performance of using heap other than sort?

My code is written in Python 2.7.

**Problem:**

Given a string and a positive integer *d*. Some characters may be repeated in the given string. Rearrange characters of the given string such that the same characters become *d* distance away from each other. Note that there can be many possible rearrangements, the output should be one of the possible rearrangements. If no such arrangement is possible, that should also be reported.
Expected time complexity is *O(n)* where *n* is length of input string.

**Examples:**

```
Input:  "abb", d = 2
Output: "bab"

Input:  "aacbbc", d = 3
Output: "abcabc"

Input: "geeksforgeeks", d = 3
Output: egkegkesfesor

Input:  "aaa",  d = 2
Output: Cannot be rearranged
```

**Source code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
def rearrange(source, distance):
    freq = defaultdict(int)
    for c in source:
        freq[c] += 1
    sorted_freq = []
    for k,v in freq.items():
        sorted_freq.append((v,k))
    sorted_freq = sorted(sorted_freq, reverse=True)
    result = [0] * len(source)
    for i, (v,k) in enumerate(sorted_freq):
        index = i
        while index < len(result) and result[index] != 0:
            index += 1
        if index == len(result):
            return None
        count = v
        while count > 0:
            result[index] = k
            index += distance
            count -= 1
            if index >= len(source) and count > 0:
                return None
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print rearrange('abb', 2)
    print rearrange('aacbbc', 3)
    print rearrange('geeksforgeeks', 3)
    print rearrange('aaa', 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of the best algorithm presented at the link is **O(n + m log m)** where *m* is the number of unique characters in the input string. As it was mentioned, since *m* always less the total number of letters in the alphabet (which is a fixed constant), if *m* is small compared to *n* the time complexity can be considered **O(n)**. There's no difference in time complexity when **O(m log m)** sorting algorithm is used to sort the frequencies instead of a heap.

Note that your implementation has time complexity **O(nm)** since you initialize `index` with `i` in every loop. Here's an alternative implementation using `Counter` instead of `defaultdict` which has the issue fixed and short comparison of the performance in degenerate case:

```
from collections import Counter

def rearrange2(s, dist):
    start = 0
    result = [None] * len(s)
    for char, count in Counter(s).most_common():
        while result[start]:
            start += 1
        end = start + dist * (count - 1) + 1
        if end > len(s):
            return None
        for i in xrange(start, end, dist):
            result[i] = char

    return ''.join(result)


def rearrange3(s, dist):
    start = 0
    result = [None] * len(s)
    for char, count in sorted(Counter(s).items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        while result[start]:
            start += 1
        end = start + dist * (count - 1) + 1
        if end > len(s):
            return None
        for i in xrange(start, end, dist):
            result[i] = char

    return ''.join(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print timeit.timeit("rearrange(src,2)", setup="from __main__ import rearrange; src='a'*10000 + 'b'*10000 + 'cdefghijk'", number=100)
    print timeit.timeit("rearrange2(src,2)", setup="from __main__ import rearrange2; src='a'*10000 + 'b'*10000 + 'cdefghijk'", number=100)
    print timeit.timeit("rearrange3(src,2)", setup="from __main__ import rearrange3; src='a'*10000 + 'b'*10000 + 'cdefghijk'", number=100)
```

Output:

```
3.23630073078
0.756645293244
0.753287190129
```

**Update:** `most_common` uses [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) [under the hood](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/collections.py#L190) which equals to heapsort in case `n` is the length of given iterable. As can be seen from the results above there's no real difference. Results of course depends on the size of the data and number of unique characters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice niemmi, and taken time to study your implementation, and compare mine to the reference implementation from the link. I think my code time complexity is `O(n + m log m)`, since in the loop `for i, (v,k) in enumerate(sorted_freq)`, I loop the number of times -- which is the same as number of unique characters (I think in your answer, `n` means length of the string, and `m` means unique number of characters in the string). If I read your comments wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: BTW, love your idea of using `Counter`.

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, you loop the outer loop `m` times which is the amount of unique characters. But think about how many times the first `while` loop gets executed. In the example I gave you on first iteration of outer loop `index` get initialized to `0` and will be executed `0` times since `result[0]` is `0`. On second time `index` is `1` and loop executes `0` times since `result[1]` is `0`. On the third round things get more interesting since `index` initializes to `2` and first free index in `result` is `20000`. 4th round `index` initializes to `3` while first free index is `20001`.

Comment: @LinMa: In my implementation `start` only moves forward which means that the inner `while` loop gets executed in total max **n** times.

Comment: Thanks niemmi, sorry for the late reply and I take time to debug my code and your code. Agree with you, that your method handles better for `index`, and also you are using `xrange` which is better than mine. Vote up for your both comments. Back to my original question, do you think using heap boost performance (comparing to the `sort` or `Counter` method we are using)? If so, why?

Comment: BTW, I think you are using `most_common`, which is similar way to sorting by frequency.

Comment: @LinMa Yes, `most_common` returns items from `Counter` in frequency order. Time complexity of using heap and sorting the frequencies is the same so there's not going to be big difference either way. With large data set and small amount of unique characters it doesn't matter since the time required to build the response string dominates the time required to sort the frequencies in one way or another. FWIW based on [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f8ec1c42360ecaeb5acca4ebcec3b3e46a4e3755/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L544) `most_common` seem to use heap based sorting.

Comment: @LinMa Expanded the answer a bit. You're basically asking if [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is faster than alternative sort algorithm.